# Evaluation of ResNet50 returns numpy array of only zeroes for binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement ResNet50 on ImageNet pre-trained weights. Below is the full code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

#Data preparation below
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

traindata = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (50, 50),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')
testdata = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (50, 50),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')
''' Building RESNET50 by freezing convolutional layers, clipping FC layers (include_top=False) and # manually including them by Dense layers. If include_top is set to True, a custom input shape of 50x50x3 cannot be provided which is imperative due to the size of the images of dataset'''

from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
resnet50model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(50, 50, 3))

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D , Flatten
resnet50_1 = Sequential()
resnet50_1.add(Flatten())
resnet50_1.add(Dense(units=1000,activation="relu"))
resnet50_1.add(Dense(units=2, activation="softmax"))
resnet50model_new = Model(inputs = resnet50model.input, outputs = resnet50_1(resnet50model.output))
#freezing convolutional layers below
for layers in (resnet50model_new.layers)[:-2]:
    print(layers)
    layers.trainable = False

#Using keras-buoy for resumable training

resnet50model_new.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), metrics=["accuracy"])
from keras_buoy.models import ResumableModel
resumable_model_resnet50 = ResumableModel(resnet50model_new, save_every_epochs = 1, custom_objects=None, to_path='dataset/saved_models/resnet50.h5')
history_resnet50 = resumable_model_resnet50.fit_generator(traindata, steps_per_epoch=157106/32, epochs=15, validation_data=testdata, validation_steps=55504/32)

#Now, to evaluate

import glob
normal_cases_dir = xxx
idc_cases_dir = xxx

normal_cases = glob.glob(normal_cases_dir+'/*.png')
idc_cases = glob.glob(idc_cases_dir+'/*.png')

test_data = []
test_labels = []
import cv2
import keras

for img in normal_cases:
    img = cv2.imread(str(img))
    img = cv2.resize(img, (50,50))
    if img.shape[2] ==1:
        img = np.dstack([img, img, img])
    else:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = img.astype(np.float32)/255.
    label = keras.utils.to_categorical(0, num_classes=2)
    test_data.append(img)
    test_labels.append(label)
                      
for img in idc_cases:
    img = cv2.imread(str(img))
    img = cv2.resize(img, (50,50))
    if img.shape[2] ==1:
        img = np.dstack([img, img, img])
    else:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = img.astype(np.float32)/255.
    label = keras.utils.to_categorical(1, num_classes=2)
    test_data.append(img)
    test_labels.append(label)
    

test_data = np.array(test_data)
test_labels = np.array(test_labels)

test_loss_resnet50, test_score_resnet50 = resnet50model_new.evaluate(test_data, test_labels, batch_size=32)
print("Loss on test set: ", test_loss_resnet50)
print("Accuracy on test set: ", test_score_resnet50)

'''The above 2 print statement gives:
Loss on test set:  0.5971299170691742
Accuracy on test set:  0.7161286
'''

preds_resnet50 = resnet50model_new.predict(test_data, batch_size = 32)
preds_resnet50 = np.argmax(preds_resnet50, axis=-1)

orig_test_labels = np.argmax(test_labels, axis=-1)

cm = confusion_matrix(orig_test_labels, preds_resnet50)
print(cm)

'''The above print statements give a confusion matrix:
array([[39748,     0],
       [15756,     0]], dtype=int64)
'''

#The above confusion matrix has zero values for false positive (FP) and true positive (TP)
#preds_resnet50 returns:
# array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
# all zeroes ^
```

The problem is that the predictions are all coming to be negative (zeroes). I found this question similar: [Keras model.predict always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900449/keras-model-predict-always-0)
However there is no correct answer and all they are suggesting is to rescale values even when evaluating on test set. I have done that and still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

model.evaluate gave an accuracy of 71.6% so it would seem the test data and test labels are correct. try printing out preds_resnet50 before you take argmax. This should show the the probability of class being label 0 and probability of class being label 1 for each sample. Might give some insight into what is going on. Try removing axis -1 from the argmax statements I don't see why it is needed.